# User GPS Location Icon Problems

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, gps, maps

I am currently displaying users locations on a Map according to their track current GPS locations.

When more than 1 user has the same current location, the respective user Icons are overlapping each other, so that I am not able to see that there are currently 2 User in that location or I can only select 1 from the Map.

See 1 example here: [Scenario 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgqTk.png)

See another example here: [Scenario 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byWH9.png)

I have added offset to the location coordinates that are the same.

Does anyone has a good suggestion to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Consider "clustering" as an approach. Instead of showing multiple annotations very close to each other, replace the overlapping group of annotations with a single annotation, showing how many items are close to each other. As you zoom in and the single annotations get further apart, they'll separate into their original annotations. As you zoom out, and annotations move closer together, and they'll start clustering together.

Apple has example code demonstrating this approach: [Decluttering a Map with MapKit Annotation Clustering](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkannotationview/decluttering_a_map_with_mapkit_annotation_clustering).

If you're using Google Maps for iOS, Google provides example code here: [Marker Clustering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/utility/marker-clustering).

Comment: I am already using clustering and in the screenshots provided I am zoomed in to the max that Google Maps would allow.

Comment: Ah, I thought you were using MapKit. I added a link to the answer showing a similar approach in Google Maps, although if you say you're already trying it, then you've probably already seen it.